# Writing a function to calculate a general mean based on specific function call by the user

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I'm using Rstudio version 1.10.136 in Mac OS Sierra 10.12.2 and here's what I want to do. I have a set of data and I created a data frame and then I filtered it after removing the NA and it looks like this:

```
            Date sulfate nitrate ID
279   2003-10-06  7.2100  0.6510  1
285   2003-10-12  5.9900  0.4280  1
291   2003-10-18  4.6800  1.0400  1
297   2003-10-24  3.4700  0.3630  1
303   2003-10-30  2.4200  0.5070  1
```

Now I want to calculate the mean based on ID call such as:

```
mean("specdata_subset", "sulfate", 1:10)
```

or

```
mean("specdata_subset", "nitrate", 40)
```

How do I write a general function that helps me calculate mean based on the ID numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `aggregate()`:

```
aggregate(nitrate~ID, df,  mean)
aggregate(sulfate~ID, df,  mean)
```

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = '
Date sulfate nitrate ID
279   2003-10-06  7.2100  0.6510  1
285   2003-10-12  5.9900  0.4280  1
291   2003-10-18  4.6800  1.0400  1
297   2003-10-24  3.4700  0.3630  1
303   2003-10-30  2.4200  0.5070  1')
```

Comment: hi Paulo, Do you mean
df <- read.table(text = '')?
because I can't include the table... I only took a snapshot to make my question more clearer. The actual data set is huge.

Comment: This is just a way to show how I read data. To read it, copy the whole snippet. And `df` is just a name created for the example. You can replace it by your `specdata_subset`.